# Any simple shape recognition libraries for Java?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, shapes

I am working on a on-screen keyboard for Android, and I need to recognize starting points, turning points and end points of lines drawn by the user on the keyboard. A simple straightening function would be nice, as it is difficult to draw a perfectly straight line even with a stylus, not to mention finger-only touchscreens today.

What I am trying to write is something like Swype.

Any good libraries that I can use or make reference to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I know at least

- [wigee](http://www.wiigee.org/) (wii targetted, but maybe a good start point)
- [iGesture](http://www.igesture.org/) (more general and powerful, but obviously harder to grasp at)